# FreeGLUT linking option

Tags: c++, opengl, compilation, glut

I started a project with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit machine), and I installed freeglut3 and freeglut3-dev. and other gl libraries installed by using nVidia's driver installer (it must be 32 bit libraries). When I compile my code, and its option was -lglut and -lGLEW. However, It turns out

```
At the preprocessor
26 #include <GL/glew.h>
27 #include <GL/glut.h>

...


:~/Downloads/Homework/src$ gcc main.cpp -o homework -lGLEW -lfreeglut
main.cpp: In function ‘void calculateFPS()’:
main.cpp:296:43: error: ‘glut_ELAPSED_TIME’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function ‘void mouse(int, int, int, int)’:
main.cpp:381:14: error: ‘glut_DOWN’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:381:37: error: ‘glut_LEFT_BUTTON’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:397:14: error: ‘glut_UP’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:397:35: error: ‘glut_LEFT_BUTTON’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function ‘void keySelect(unsigned char, int, int)’:
main.cpp:442:49: error: ‘glutCloseFunc’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:448:93: error: ‘glProgramUniform1i’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:489:25: error: ‘glut_RGBA’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:489:37: error: ‘glut_DOUBLE’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:489:51: error: ‘glut_DEPTH’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:489:64: error: ‘glut_MULTISAMPLE’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:493:20: error: ‘glut_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:493:49: error: ‘glut_ACTION_glutMAINLOOP_RETURNS’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:493:82: error: ‘glutSetOption’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:494:28: error: ‘glutCloseFunc’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:496:32: error: ‘glutInitContextVersion’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:497:25: error: ‘glut_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:497:49: error: ‘glutInitContextFlags’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:498:27: error: ‘glut_CORE_PROFILE’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:498:45: error: ‘glutInitContextProfile’ was not declared in this scope
```

I don't know why this happened, and I attached my GL folder

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `-L` switch to point to the location of the library and `-lfreeglut` to link to freeglut?

Comment: @remyabel I haven't yet. I will try, and tell you

Comment: @remyabel Same situation was happened. :( I edited.

Comment: Try `#include <GL/freeglut.h>`, `-L/usr/lib` or wherever freeglut is located.

Comment: @remyabel I've already tried `26 #include <GL/glew.h>
 27 #include <GL/glut.h>
 28 #include <GL/freeglut.h>
 29 #include <GL/freeglut_ext.h>
 30 #include <GL/freeglut_std.h>
`

Comment: The prefix of the glut defines is all uppercase (for example glut_ELAPSED_TIME is GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME). The missing function definitions are in freeglut_ext.h, as they are not implemented in GLUT 3.7. As GL/glut.h includes only the standard parts of the freeglut library change it to GL/freeglut.h or include GL/freeglut_ext.h too.